# how to change the background image of the cell when poping back to the viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am changing the cell background image when the user selects each row.Like this`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell.png"]]; 

    } 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell_check.png"]];
  if (indexPath != nil) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   }




}
```

`it is working fine.My problem is from the detailed view when i am poping back to the previous view Ie to the tableview controller the changed background image in the tableview stays like as.But i need it to be the normal one.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reload the table when your controller reappears, it will reload the data, and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will not get called, so your cell will have the initial background.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(animated){
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [instanceToYourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: in this case you should post your cellForRowAtIndexPath, let us see the way you display the cells initially.

Comment: thanks for the advice .The problem is i am checking whether cell==nil or not in that loop only i am changing the background thats the reason

Comment: exactly, that's why I asked for the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to see it.

Comment: just set the background of the cell after the if(cell == nil){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you should restore the cellBackground, and on viewWillAppear call reloadData